# VueJs $router not working after download .docx from Axios request using Blob

Tags: javascript, vue.js, blob

Here is my **function:**

After `link.click()` document downloaded but `this.$router.push()` stop working. What is the problem?

```
 axios.post(apiurl + "api/appform-list/",
              {
                this.data
              },
              {
                responseType: "arraybuffer",
              }
            )
            .then((response) => {
              let blob = new Blob([response.data]),
                url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              const link = document.createElement("a");
              link.href = url;
              link.setAttribute("download", "GeneratedDoc.docx");
              document.body.appendChild(link);
              link.click();
          
    
              this.RemoveInputs();
              this.$router.push("/clientlist");
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
             console.log(error)
            });
```

Comment: Please share if there is an error on console

Comment: It works, I have not looked at the error before. There was a problem with function this.RemoveInputs(), It caused the $router. Thanks for pointing!